# Concoct an alternating series which diverges that is alternating, the limit goes to 0, but is NOT always decreasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Basically need an example of a divergent series that is alternating and the limit goes to 0.

Comment: How can it be both alternating and always positive?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  I meant that An (the non-alternating part) is positive.  I have edited the question.